# What is a script that will accept a username as a command line argument and will display only that user's account information?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am learning to write scripts and I can't seem to find a way to get a script to accept a username as a command line argument and then give me the output for only that username's account information.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "account information"?

Comment: I'm looking for user information.  For instance, the username, who they are, home directory, groups, disk usage and last login.  I have a script already that will pull all the users' information, but not one specific user once I enter that user's name.  I don't want the other users' information, only the one I enter.

Comment: Most of that will be in /etc/passwd, and can be isolated and extracted with grep and sed.  Disk use will have to be pulled in a more complicated manner.  A `du --max-depth=0 -h $HOME` would work for the home directory (replacing $HOME with the proper directory).  `last $USER` will work for last login, which pulls information from `/var/log/wtmp` in most cases.

Comment: Thanks @Taywee for your help.  I actually have script that will do that, but it pulls all the users information. I was trying to modify the script so it asked for the user's info I wanted, and then only gives me that user, not all of them. I'm trying to figure out how to manipulate the script, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try grepping for just the specific username as the first field before processing /etc/passwd: `grep -E "^$USER:"`

Comment: In the good old says before the Internet was evil, there was a program called finger...

Comment: There is already a program called finger that does that. So try: `finger root` for example. Newer Linux distros have a program called `pinky` as well.  Both finger and pinky will format the outputs.

Answer (score 3):

### Why you shouldn't do it

There are several command-line programs that get you information from /etc/passwd, /etc/groups and other account information such as reading .plan, .project and .pgpkey

Typically you do not WANT to use /etc/passwd directly because there may be other databases like NIS+ or LDAP maintaining your account information on the system.

Software that gets you information about account:

`finger` — Almost guaranteed to be present everywhere, appeared in BSD 3.0
finger is a network aware program and is serviced by fingerd(8) daemon for remote fingering.

`pinky — A lightweight finger program (no networking support I think) part of GNU coreutils

`id` – Available on most System V compatible environments (if I recall correctly?)

`who` – display login information, it will also display if users are accepting messages over the talk/write protocol and also if they will accept `talk` `write` requests on your control terminal (see mesg(1) for details)

## Okay maybe you want to do it for fun

Here is a quick and dirty way that is limited to local use:

```
#!/bin/bash

user="$1"


awk -F: '/^'$user'/ { print "Login: " $1 " UID: " $3 " GID: " $4 \
           " GECOS: " $5 " Home Directory: " $6 " Shel: " $7 }' /etc/passwd
```

You can similarly access .plan etc. from the user's home directory.

Read up passwd(5) man page, `man 5 passwd` to get details of the password structure:

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged this Linux, Bash, and Unix, it's likely that the information you are looking for is in /etc/passwd.

Try `man 5 passwd` for information on the fields.  This is the information stored by the OS in reference to users.  Deeper information will need to be probed further.

A simple example would follow:

```
#!/bin/sh

grep -E "^$1:" /etc/passwd | sed 's/\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\)/Username: \1\nUID: \3\nGID: \4\nComments: \5\nHome: \6\nShell: \7/'
```

And it has this example output for me:

```
% /tmp/username.sh taylor
Username: taylor
UID: 1001
GID: 100
Comments: 
Home: /home/taylor
Shell: /bin/zsh
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you can use `getent passwd` for transparently retrieving user information from the backends configured in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` (e.g. the local `passwd` file, NIS, LDAP, …). Example:

```
$ getent passwd jsmith
jsmith:x:1234:100:John Smith,,,:/home/jsmith:/bin/bash
```

`getent` is not available on some other Unix flavors, though, like Mac OS X.